# cross browser testing using codedui?

Tags: c#, .net, cross-browser, coded-ui-tests

i have issue in cross browser testing using codedui.
Using below code,

```
Process.Start("firefox", url);
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "firefox";
Browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri(url));
Keyboard.SendKeys("^{0}");
```

all code developed in IE . but now i have to execute code in firefox or chrome.I am going to execute the code in forefox.I am using this code  here

```
Browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri(url));
```

in this line getting error like "An error occurred while connecting to Firefox".how to resolve this issue?I installed selenium components also. if i remove this line I am getting diffrent error like " Unable to find browser"...Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Out of the box Visual Studio doesn't support cross browser CodedUI testing.

You're going to need to install Selenium components to allow for cross browser testing in Visual Studio.

Details on that can be found here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/30/introducing-cross-browser-testing-with-coded-ui-tests.aspx

Selenium components can be found here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/11cfc881-f8c9-4f96-b303-a2780156628d

Comment: Official documentation is now available at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835758.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CodedUI doesn't support playback on very many different browsers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742(VS.100).aspx

There are some other tools out there http://watin.org/ is one, but I can't find anything myself that will really solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "firefox";
BrowserWindow WebApp;
WebApp.CopyFrom(BrowserWindow.LaunchUrl(new System.Uri(url)));
```

I set up something similar to the following and it works well (I hand code everything, bypassing the UIMap).

```
public class WebApp : BrowserWindow
{
   private string _url;

   public WebApp(string url)
   {
      //define search properties using this keyword so the web application can be treated as a browser
      _url = url;
      BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome";
      this.CopyFrom(BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri(url));
   }
}
```

You can overload the constructor, of course, by adding a parameter for the browser to use or whether to start up the browser or not.

By setting up the web application as a BrowserWindow, you can have one open and ready and the playback engine should find it. I find this helps when working on tests (in IE).

Just a reminder, you do need the Selenium plug-in and that plug-in will only work for playback, not recording.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In our environment, we set up the Launch() method by doing the following:

```
public void LaunchBrowser(string uri)
{
    BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "firefox";
    BrowserWindow myBrowser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri(uri));
}
```

One thing to note is that if there is a firefox process already running in the background, the WebDriver will not launch a new instance, so be sure that all instances of firefox are shut down before the LaunchBrowser() is called.  I've found that there are Java plugins that can keep it running in the background, so try to disable those that you don't need.  Another good place to look, if you check your Task Manager and this is the case, is [here.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-hangs-or-not-responding?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Firefox+hangs#w_hang-at-exit)